# Java stream, get multiple properties from object

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have an object like this:

```java
public class Transaction {
    private long buyerId;
    private long sellerId;
... }
```

Given a `List<Transaction>`, I want the ids of all the buyers/sellers involved in those transactions, e.g. in a `Collection<Long>`. This is my working solution:

```java
List<Transaction> transactions = getTransactions();
Stream<Long> buyerIds = transactions.stream().map( Transaction::getBuyerId );
Stream<Long> sellerIds = transactions.stream().map( Transaction::getSellerId );
Collection<Long> allBuyerSellerIds = Stream.concat( buyerIds, sellerIds )
                .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

However, it would be nice if I could do this without iterating through `transactions` twice. How can I do this? i.e. I want to iterate through `transactions` with a stream, and get multiple properties each time.

Thanks.

Comment: return array of 2 `long` elements

Comment: Are you sure you want toList() rather than toSet()?  A List may have duplicates, while a Set will not.

Comment: Fair point, thanks @VGR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` since you want them in one collection in the end anyway.

```
getTransactions().stream()
 .flatMap(t -> Stream.of(t.getBuyerId(), t.getSellerId()))
 .collect(toList());
```

If you didn't want them in a single collection, you might be better off with a conventional loop instead.